# How to merge two models in tensorflow?

Tags: graph, model, tensorflow

I am working on face recognition using tensorflow.
I have a graph that I am using to train two different model and each model have 10 classes.
Now my question is, can I create a single model of 20 classes with the help of these two models.
Please respond to this question. If you want more information, let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the structure of the two models? they have the same layers except the last softmax layer?

Comment: Thanks to respond.
Yes, the structure has same layers with same number of neurons.
And the softmax layer too has the same number of output(it is 10).

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you to merge two graphs mainly because paramater trained with 20 categories are quite different from the merged one with each 10 categories, but if you still want to do it, here is some advice

first import you graph with meta_graph_def or graph_def

second extract "bottleneck" tensor in the graph, you can do it with `bottleneck = graph.get_tensor_by_name("your_tensor_name")`

third read your pretrained values from disk(checkpoint), the class `tf.train.NewCheckpointReader` can be help

last step, build a constant tensor upon bottleneck tensor with values read from the third step.

Comment: Thanks @Jie.Zhou, it seems somewhat helpful.
But I am very clear with the last step. Can you refer me any link regarding this.
For **third read your pretrained values from disk(checkpoint), the class tf.train.NewCheckpointReader**,
it will read the pretrained values of the one model only.
What about the other model, and how the other models with affect here.

Comment: @Akki see docs for these two functions in tensorflow website: `tf.train.import_meta_graph` and `tf.import_graph_def` (they are offen used when trying to restore a model)

Comment: Sorry for the first comment here  **But I am very clear with the last step.**. Actually it is **I am not very clear with the last step**.

Comment: @Akki once you have a read your weights from checkpoint file, let's say two numpy.array called `w1` and `w2`, concat these two weights into with `w = np.hstack([w1, w2])`, then create a const tensor `softmax_w = tf.constant(w)`, calculate logits `logits = tf.matmul(bottleneck, softmax_w)`(omit bias for simplicity), then probability `prob = tf.nn.softmax(logits)`

Comment: Thanks @Jie.Zhou, I will try this.

Comment: Hi @Jie.Zhou, I tried to implement the same as you advised.
But here, I am taking bottleneck of one model, but the other model also has some weights and biases in the hidden layers which are the key of the model. And to add the weight and biases of only the last dense layer for predicting 20 classes doesn't make sense. Is this the reason you don't recommend to merge it?
If no, then why don't you recommend.
And if still I am doing something wrong in the code, please point that out.

Comment: @Akki exactly that's the reason